# I didn't find 1.6.2.jar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I went to minecraft, then versions, then 1.6.2 and i didn't find 1.6.2.jar!
I already search and I never found anything!
I'm sorry if I've got some languange errors, english isn't my first languange.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: You can get old versions by using the launcher.  Just set up a new profile and specify which version you want.

Comment: You should check again because they changed the names of the files when the new launcher came out.

Answer (score 2):

In order to grab an old version, you must edit your profile in the new launcher and select the version you wish to download. After you have loaded up that version of Minecraft at least once, you can then find it in the versions folder.

Comment: Already did that.

Answer (score -3):

maybe the error is in your minecraft, try redownloading it.

Comment: Already did that